# The Prime Grid Game

Tags: code-golf, number, primes, grid

I had fun solving this, so I offer this golf challenge.

The objective of this **golf** is to find the largest prime number that can be constructed using the given instructions.

You should accept 3x3 grid of single digits as input. (It's up to you how you want to do that, but specify that in your program.)

You can move along the grid orthogonally (left, right, up or down), and as you move, you keep appending the digits you walk across.

E.g.

```
1 2 3
3 5 6 
1 8 9
```

Say we start at `1`,
we can form the number 1236589 but **cannot** form 15.

You have to evaluate every starting position.

If a prime cannot be found, print `-1`, else print the prime itself.

Shortest code wins, make sure it runs within 10 secs.

Have Fun!

Edit: Use one position exactly once, in the entire number.

Here's a test case

**Input:**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**Output:**
69854123

Comment: I presume we can't repeat positions?

Comment: No, You cannot. Otherwise it'll be an infinite search :) Sorry, forgot to mention that. Editing.

Comment: I can haz test cases?

Comment: @MtnViewMark, i haz postd testcase, and confirmed your answer aswell. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Haskell, 239 characters

```
p=2:q[3..]
q=filter(#p)
n#(x:y)=n==x||n`mod`x/=0&&(n`div`x<x||n#y)
(n§m)q=n:maybe[](\i->[q-4,q-1,q+1,q+4]>>=(n*10+i)§filter(/=(q,i))m)(lookup q m)
i=[0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10]
main=getLine>>=print.maximum.(-1:).q.(i>>=).(0§).zip i.map read.words
```

Input is given as a single line of nine numbers:

```
$> echo 1 2 3  3 5 6  1 8 9 | runhaskell 2485-PrimeGrid.hs
81356321
$> echo 1 2 3  4 5 6  7 8 9 | runhaskell 2485-PrimeGrid.hs
69854123
$> echo 1 1 1  1 1 1  1 1 1 | runhaskell 2485-PrimeGrid.hs
11
$> echo 2 2 2  2 2 2  2 2 2 | runhaskell 2485-PrimeGrid.hs
2
$> echo 4 4 4  4 4 4  4 4 4 | runhaskell 2485-PrimeGrid.hs
-1
```

Comment: I can confirm your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

### Python, <strike>286</strike> 274 chars

```
I=lambda:raw_input().split()
m=['']
G=m*4+I()+m+I()+m+I()+m*4
def B(s,p):
 d=G[p]
 if''==d:return-1
 G[p]='';s+=d;n=int(s)
 r=max(n if n>1and all(n%i for i in range(2,n**.5+1))else-1,B(s,p-4),B(s,p+4),B(s,p-1),B(s,p+1))
 G[p]=d;return r
print max(B('',i)for i in range(15))
```

This does give a deprecation warning for the float argument to `range`.  Ignore it, or spend 5 more chars to wrap `int()` around it.